# VBA: Run as query in a Sheet of the same Book

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in file, and what I need to do is to run a query in it, as it was a SQL table, or find a similar code in VBA. Almost everything I found about it, was about running a query in Access database using VBA in an Excel file.

In my file I have a Sheet that I need to use as database, and a second Sheet that need to show some information when I run a macro. Imagine that I have a sheet like this:

```
|Number|Field1|
|  5   |AAAAAA|
|  4   |BBBBBB|
|  8   |CCCCCC|
|  3   |AAAAAA|
|  4   |BBBBBB|
|  2   |AAAAAA|
|  1   |CCCCCC|
```

This query should sum only the numbers where Field1 has a determined value, and should sum all the lines in the sheet. The number of lines vary depending the day.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the `sumif` forumla. (So, you don't need a macro for that):

```
=SUMIF(B2:B8;"BBBBBB";A2:A8)
```

This sums the numbers in A2 to A8 if the mathching rown in B2 to B8 contains "BBBBBB"